# Improve wording for "Welcome back" message

Tags: feature-request, wording, welcome-back

Every time I see the welcome back banner

> [image: Welcome back]

I think that some time ago I've visited **that question's page**, but actually this message is about visiting **the site**.

Could we improve the wording to refer that? For instance:

> Welcome back **to {SiteName}**! If you found this question useful,
> don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.

Comment: I never read this as "welcome back to the question", always as "welcome back to the site". The more problematic part for me is the advice to vote the answers up if the question is useful, it would be better to upvote an answer _only_ if that answer itself is useful. And also I find it odd to be reminded about voting since I am a frequent visitor to other sites in the network - but I have to admit that the banner sometimes has had the desired effect of reminding me to vote.